# How to show the comments from an API which is in tree form in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api

API: https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/items/12701272

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import "./index.css";

const Tree = ({ data = []}) => {
  return (
    <div className="d-tree">
      <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
        {data.map((tree) => (
          <TreeNode node={tree} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const TreeNode = ({ node }) => {
  const [childVisible, setChildVisiblity] = useState(false);

  const hasChild = node.children ? true : false;

  return (
    <li className="d-tree-node border-0">
      <div className="d-flex" onClick={(e) => setChildVisiblity((v) => !v)}>
        {hasChild && (
          <div
            className={`d-inline d-tree-toggler ${
              childVisible ? "active" : ""
            }`}
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-right" />
          </div>
        )}

        <div className="col d-tree-head">
          <i className={`mr-1 `}> </i>
          {node.text}
        </div>
      </div>

      {hasChild && childVisible && (
        <div className="d-tree-content">
          <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
            <Tree data={node.children} />
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </li>
  );
};

export default Tree;
```

I want to show all the comments in tree format,
I tried by above method but it shows error: `TypeError: data.map is not a function`
The data passed in tree function is the api converted into data.
What to do?

Comment: You need to check if data is an array or not. data.map is not a function means it's not an array, try console logging it and check whether it is an Array !

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error  `TypeError: data.map is not a function` because data is not an array but an object. The response from the API is -

```
{
id:12701272,
created_at:"2016-10-13T15:15:48.000Z",
created_at_i:1476371748,
type:"story",
author:"fatihky",
title:"Google's “Director of Engineering” Hiring Test",
url:"http://www.gwan.com/blog/20160405.html",
text:null,
points:1764,
parent_id:null,
story_id:null,
children:(190) [...],
options:(0) [...]
}
```

The comment is inside the the object which is inside the array having children as the key.